# Run batch jobs in background after server logout

Tags: shell, unix, parallel-processing, batch-processing, gnu-screen

I have a **csh-shell** skript which starts **N** batch-jobs on a server. After one job is completed, the skript runs another job until all runs are completed.
This works perfectly fine as long as I am logged on the server.

Since the runs will take several days, I have to logout from time to time and here comes the problem:
Even though I run the script *jobs.sh* which then initiates the batch jobs in *batch.sh* using the **nohup** command, the task stops after the started batch jobs have finished and no new batch jobs are initiated. How can I prevent this?

```
    $ nohup jobs.sh
```

which looks more or less like this:

```
    #!/bin/csh -f
    ...
    eval "nice +5 batch.sh <options>"
```

The *batch.sh* routine looks like this:

```
    time program.x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start your script inside a `screen` session, it won't get killed as you logout / get disconnected. You can just re-attach the session later when you log back in to check on things.

If you're new to `screen` you might want to check out [this page](http://aperiodic.net/screen/start):

> Screen is a text-based program usually described as a window manager or terminal multiplexer. While it does a great many things, its two biggest features are its detachability and its multiplexing. The detachability means that you can run programs from within screen, detach and logout, then log in later, reattach, and the programs will still be there. The multiplexing means that you can have multiple programs running within a single screen session, each within its own window. You can display multiple windows at once, or just switch between them, even if you only have a single terminal window to use.

`tmux` is another similar program.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). It allows you to have several shells open at once. And you can disconnect from those running shells (i.e. close session with Putty) and they will keep doing their thing.

With `nohup` you can't resume interaction.